# Fixing an element on Y axis, but scrolling with page on x axis?

Tags: html, css, scroll

Is it possible to fix an element to a 'y' position on the page, but when scrolling left and right, this element scrolls on the x-axis as well?

In my case, I have a table of data which has 20 columns in total (far too many to display without page scrolling). I would like to fix the table headers to the top of the page, however this also fixes x-scrolling so when scrolling left and right, the headers do not move. Is it possible to only fix the y-positioning of an element?

I've created a basic fiddle showing a standard table here: http://jsfiddle.net/0n9d92er/. Basically, I want header 1-20 fixed at the top (for vertical scrolling), but when scrolling to the right, I should be able to see every header from 1 to 20 (when horizontally scrolling).

```css
.header {
    width: 2000px;
}
.tg  {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}
.tg td {
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:10px 5px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
}
.tg th {
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:10px 5px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
}
.tg .tg-i7wz {
    font-size:20px
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-i7wz">HEADER 1</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 2</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 3</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 4</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 5</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 6</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 7</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 8</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 9</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 10</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 11</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 12</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 13</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 14</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 15</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 16</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 17</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 18</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 19</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 20</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">CONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENT </td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">CONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENT</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">CONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENT</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">CONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENT</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">CONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENT</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">CONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENT</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">CONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENT</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">CONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENT</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">CONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENT</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Do you want a pure css solution or it can be jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example that does not require jQuery, and uses JavaScript to float the header down as the page scrolls:

```js
var thead = document.querySelector(".tg tr:first-child");
window.onscroll = function() {
    thead.style["-webkit-transform"] = "translateY(" + window.scrollY + "px)";
    thead.style.transform = "translateY(" + window.scrollY + "px)";
};
```

```css
.header {
    width: 2000px;
}
.tg  {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}
.tg td {
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:10px 5px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
}
.tg th {
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:10px 5px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
}
.tg .tg-i7wz {
    font-size:20px;
}

.tg tr:first-child {
    background-color: white;
    outline: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-i7wz">HEADER 1</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 2</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 3</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 4</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 5</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 6</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 7</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 8</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 9</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 10</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 11</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 12</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 13</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 14</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 15</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 16</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 17</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 18</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 19</th>
    <th class="tg-031e">HEADER 20</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">CONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENT </td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">CONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENT</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">CONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENT</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">CONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENT</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">CONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENT</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">CONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENT</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">CONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENT</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">CONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENT</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">CONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENTCONTENT CONTENT</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JSFiddle Version: http://jsfiddle.net/0n9d92er/4/